# Java ME Drawing multiple dynamic Sprites on GameCanvas

Tags: graphics, java-me, midp, lcdui, gamecanvas

I want to draw on GameCanvas multiple dynamic Sprites such as gun shots.

I have 2 main classes: `GameCanvas` and `GameController`

`GameController` holds a Vector of my gun shots.

GameCanvas has an access to `GameController`'s Vector of Sprite and
it also has a `render()` method which draws Sprites on screen.

```
private void render() {
            Graphics g = getGraphics();

            layerManager.setViewWindow(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            layerManager.paint(g, 0, 0);

            flushGraphics();
}
```

LayerManager holds all the Sprites I want to draw.

How can I draw all objects in `GameController`'s Vector on screen?

Comment: If layerManager is already holding all the other Sprites you want to draw, then why aren't you also adding each gunshot to layerManager when the player fires?

Comment: So I have to hold a reference to GameCanvas in GameController, right?
isn't it a little bit messy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think it could be done like this:

```
Graphics g = getGraphics(); // No need to get this each time you render. Get it once outside the render function

private void render() {

  layerManager.setViewWindow(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
  layerManager.paint(g, 0, 0);

  // Loop through the vector
  for (Enumeration en = gunshotVector.elements(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
    ((Sprite)en).paint(g);
  }

  flushGraphics();
}
```